# How to merge object animations into one..?

Tags: animation

I have 6 wheels, each animated; I need to have all animations with just one name ('_AnimWheel'...) for the complete animation to be recognised by the destination train software for this model. How may I combine all of these animations (and more to come later, for the loco valve gear...) into just one animation, please..? Here's a screenshot of the current state of the model...

[image]

Thanks in advance; meanwhile... have a great day.